# EF. Mocking ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking

I have class model Role:

```
public partial class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

while UnitTesting I need to mock it.
So I have the code:

```
public class RoleControllerTest
{
    private IUnitOfWork fakeRepo;
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Mock<IUnitOfWork> mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.roleRepository.Get(null)).Returns(new[]{
           new Role{Id=1, RoleName="Admin",MissingArgument},
           new Role{Id=2,RoleName="User",MissingArgument}
        });
    }
}
```

I don't have idea how to mock

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Tried null but this alsa returns error.
Can you suggest me what variable and what type I should pass in place of `MissingArgument`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `Moq` - `Users` is just a property on your `Role` class for which you want to generate fake data, so you can continue to use object initializer syntax to initialize it in the `Returns` of your mocked Get implementation, like so:

```
    Mock<IUnitOfWork> mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.roleRepository.Get(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(new[]{
           new Role
           {
             Id=1, 
             RoleName="Admin", 
             Users = new List<User>
              {
                 new User 
                 { 
                   // Set SomeUserProperties Here 
                 },
                 // Add another User here if needed
              }},
           new Role
           {
               Id=2,
               RoleName="User" 
               // Add users here
           }
          }
         );
```

If you find yourself needing to return the same fake data across multiple unit tests, you can create a set of common canned `static readonly` objects or use an [object mother factory](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ObjectMother.html) for various `users` and `roles`, which will DRY up your code.